# How do cell phones modulate transmission data

Tags: transmitter, cellphone

Is it digital, as in the the phone transmitter is turned on and off corresponding to the bits, or is it FM or AM? at what frequency? and how is it that they can transmit what appears to be over large areas without (what again, seems to be) much power consumption.

Comment: Depends on which technology you're talking about.

Comment: what types of technologies are there? or at least, what are the most prominent ones?

Comment: [Lots.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_mobile_phone_standards#Comparison_table)

Comment: You should do some googling else this question becomes too complex to answer xxxx

Answer (score 1):

Cell phones use digital modulation. Two prominent technologies are GSM and CDMA, each of which has a good introductory article in Wikipedia.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_telephony
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDMA
Transmitter power is conserved by transmitting only to the base station of the nearest cell.